# how to update a UIView Without using the main thread

Tags: iphone, multithreading, cocoa-touch, animation, uikit

HI,

I have a bit of a threading conundrum. I have a UIView that draws an arc over time depending on the rate at which certain things are occurring in my code. It can never stop drawing and the rate at which it draws can change.

When I started out doing this I thought to myself that I should calculate the percent of the arc to draw in a separate thread. This is fine. The problem is that in order to redraw the arc based on the new percent I need to perform the updateArc function on the main thread.

Seeing as my requirement is for it to continuously update the main thread is never free to do anything else. If I don't use the main thread to call the arc update function the update never happens.

How can I can continually update a UIView without interrupting the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: You can use display link.

Comment: thats the problem. I need to update the arc several times a second to achieve a smooth animation. Because I need to update the UI so regularly the UI is permanently blocked.

Comment: Are you sure you cant do the work on a separate thread? As that would be the best solution. However you could also use display link, however that wont work on iOS<3.1 and they can change their implementation so that it does not work on a seperate thread.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: using displaylink worked! I can continually draw without interrupting the main thread. You should put would comment as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed-up your drawing would be to only redraw the portion of your arc which has changed between updates and only invalidate that portion of your screen for redraw. In `setNeedsRedraw` you can specify which rect gets marked for redraw.

But at RTS said there is no way to draw in a background thread.